# Are there any overheads in repeatedly casting between float and double

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, llvm

Mixing various Frameworks and Libraries I often see code like this

```
float floatValue = 0.5f;
float returnValue = 0.0f;

returnValue = (float)[object someMethod:(double)floatValue]; //returns double
```

Is there any overhead in casting back-and-forth between `double` and `float`?

I'm mainly interested in [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) and the [llvm](/questions/tagged/llvm) compiler but would happy up vote answers for other languages and compilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting between `float` and `double` is a single conversion instruction in either direction on both ARM and x86.  There are some cases in which the compiler is able to eliminate these conversions (when it can prove that they would not effect the result of the computation), but that will not be the case in examples like those you listed.

So, there is a small amount of overhead.  A few extra casts at high-level interface boundaries won't have a noticeable effect.  However, you don't want to convert every value in a tight loop if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an overhead because the cast causes a conversion. The formats in the cpu are different.

Worrying about that and writing code to reduce it is "pre-mature optimization", just don't. If there are performance problems use instruments, find them and fix. A "Best Practice" is to write the most clear code.